# How check a string value inside a list on a if statement?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
s = ['01','06','11','16','21','26','31','36','41','46','51','56']

while True:
    for a in s:
        if time.strftime('%S') == a:             
            print 'YES'
        else:
            print time.strftime('%S')
            time.sleep(1)
            print a
```

And it doesn't work.

Any ideas how to make it work?
In case, everytime the `%S` gets some of the value in `s`, it prints the `'YES'`.

Comment: Why os not working? There is an error? And what exactly should your program do?

Comment: I agree with Rik. You should make it a habit to include the traceback in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `sleep` on every loop and look for the current seconds in your list of matches:

```
>>> import time
>>>
>>> matches = ['01','06','11','16','21','26','31','36','41','46','51','56']
>>>
>>> while True:
...     seconds = time.strftime('%S')
...     if seconds in matches:
...         print('YES')
...     else:
...         print(seconds)
...     time.sleep(1)
...
07
08
09
10
YES
12
13
14
15
YES
17
18
19
```